# Replace 3 or more occurrences of character within string

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to find 3 or more occurrences of a within a std::string in order to replace.

For example:

```
std::string foo = "This is a\n\n\n test";
std::string bar = "This is a\n\n\n\n test";
std::string baz = "This is a\n\n\n\n\n test";
std::string boo = "This is a\n\n\n\n\n\n test";
// ... etc.
```

Should *all* be converted to:

```
std::string expectedResult = "This is a\n\n test";
```

Vanilla stl would be appreciated (no regexp libs or boost) if possible.

Comment: @Öö Tiib: I can brute force it by counting consecutive occurrences to get the begin and end pos but I was hoping for a more STL way of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should find consecutive \n and replace them:

```
size_type i = foo.find("\n\n\n");
if (i != string::npos) {
    size_type j = foo.find_first_not_of('\n', i);
    foo.replace(i, j - i, "\n\n");
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of find_first_not_of ... that should help

Comment: Find_first_of works by finding *characters* and not substrings ... I'll see if I can adjust to using find and update if I get a working solution.

Comment: I should also note that replace actually takes the number of characters to replace ... so `foo.replace(i, j - i, "\n\n");` is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to process each string you are interested in modifying:

Read each string one character a time. Keep track of 2 char variables: a and b. For each character c you read, do:

```
if ( a != b ) {
    a = b;
    b = c;
} else if ( a == b ) {
    if ( a == c ) {
        // Put code here to remove c from your string at this index
    }
}
```

I am not 100% sure if you can use something from STL directly to accomplish what you are asking, but as you can see this logic isn't much code to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find and replace. (this will replace "\n\n\n..." -> "\n\n"). You can pass position to string::find  so that you don't have to search the start of the string again (optimization)

```
  int pos = 0;
  while ((pos = s.find ("\n\n\n", pos)) != s.npos)
    s.replace (pos, 3, "\n\n", 2);
```

And this will replace "\n\n\n\n.." -> "\n"

```
  int pos = 0;
  while ((pos = s.find ("\n\n", pos)) != s.npos)
    s.replace (pos, 2, "\n", 1);
```